# How to output my dictionary to an Excel sheet in Python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

Background: My first Excel-related script. Using openpyxl. 
There is an Excel sheet with loads of different types of data about products in different columns.

My goal is to extract certain types of data from certain columns (e.g. price, barcode, status), assign those to the unique product code and then output product code, price, barcode and status to a new excel doc.

I have succeeded in extracting the data and putting it the following dictionary format:

```
productData = {'AB123': {'barcode': 123456, 'price': 50, 'status': 'NEW'}
```

My general thinking on getting this output to a new report is something like this (although I know that this is wrong):

```
newReport = openpyxl.Workbook()
newSheet = newReport.active
newSheet.title = 'Output'

newSheet['A1'].value = 'Product Code'
newSheet['B1'].value = 'Price'
newSheet['C1'].value = 'Barcode'
newSheet['D1'].value = 'Status'

for row in range(2, len(productData) + 1):
    newSheet['A' + str(row)].value = productData[productCode]
    newSheet['B' + str(row)].value = productPrice
    newSheet['C' + str(row)].value = productBarcode
    newSheet['D' + str(row)].value = productStatus

newReport.save('ihopethisworks.xlsx')
```

What do I actually need to do to output the data?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Pandas for that. It has the following syntax:

```
df = pd.read_excel('your_file.xlsx')
df['Column name you want'].to_excel('new_file.xlsx')
```

You can do a lot more with it. Openpyxl might not be the right tool for your task (Openpyxl is too general).

P.S. I would leave this in the comments, but stackoverflow, in their widom decided to let anyone to leave answers, but not to comment.

Comment: It's not clear from the post whether the data is in columns. In any case, what you suggest is directly possible in openpyxl `ws['A']`

Answer (score 0):

The logic you use to extract the data is missing but I suspect the best approach is to use it to loop over the two worksheets in parallel. You can then avoid using a dictionary entirely and just append loops to the new worksheet.

Pseudocode:

```
ws1 # source worksheet
ws2 # new worksheet

product = []
code = ws1[…] # some lookup
barcode = ws1[…]
price = ws1[…]
status = ws1[…]

ws2.append([code, price, barcode, status])
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas will work best for this
here are some examples

```
import pandas as pd

#df columns:  Date    Open    High     Low   Close     Volume
#reading data from an excel 
df = pd.read_excel('GOOG-NYSE_SPY.xls')

#set index to the column of your choice, in this case it would be date
df.set_index('Date', inplace = True)

#choosing the columns of your choice for further manipulation
df = df[['Open', 'Close']]

#divide two colums to get the % change
df = (df['Open'] - df['Close']) / df['Close'] * 100


print(df.head())
```